# Require scalar multiplication of a generic type with f64 in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, multiplication

I feel that I have two halves of a problem and don't know how to fit them together.
On the one hand there is the "derive_more" crate which allows to automatically derive "Add" and "Mul" (+ more) traits for *specific* types. I have used it successfully to implement the function below for a *specific* type for which I automatically derived these traits.

On the other hand I want to write a generic function that will later use these "Add" and "Mul" (+ more) traits. It does not work however. (For anyone interested, I want to implement a generic Runge-Kutta function for solving differential equations).

```
pub fn update_rk4<T>(f: fn(&T) -> T, state: &mut T, dt: f64)
where
    T: Sized 
    + std::ops::Mul<Output = T> 
    + std::ops::Add<Output = T> 
    + std::ops::AddAssign,
{
    // runge kutta 4 method creates 4 "helper steps"
    let k1 = f(state);
    let k2 = f(&(*state + k1 * 0.5 * dt));
    let k3 = f(&(*state + k2 * 0.5 * dt));
    let k4 = f(&(*state + k3 * dt));

    *state += (k1 + k2 * 2.0 + k3 * 2.0 + k4) * (1.0 / 6.0 * dt);
}
```

I am stuck here. I get lots of error messages like this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/integrator.rs:7:32
  |
1 | pub fn update_rk4_with_f<T>(f: fn(&T) -> T, state: &mut T, dt: f64)
  |                          - this type parameter
...
7 |     let k2 = f(&(*state + k1 * 0.5 * dt));
  |                                ^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found floating-point number
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
                       found type `{float}`
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also: what is the name of the problem that I am trying to solve? I think I am also missing a good search term to put into google.

**Edit:**

With the help of the nice answer from Matthieu M. below I fixed my problem. I tried replacing "Mul<Output = T>" with "Mul<Rhs = f64, Output = T>", but still got errors. It turned out that the idea was the right one, because in the trait implementation "Rhs" defaults to "T", so it has to be set manually - but without the "Rhs". The solution is simply "Mul<f64, Output = T>". Then with the "Copy" trait it all worked. The final working code looks like this:

```
pub fn update_rk4<T>(f: fn(&T) -> T, state: &mut T, dt: f64)
where
    T: Sized + Copy
    + std::ops::Mul<f64, Output = T> 
    + std::ops::Add<T, Output = T> 
    + std::ops::AddAssign,
{
    // runge kutta 4 method creates 4 "helper steps"
    let k1 = f(state);
    let k2 = f(&(*state + k1 * 0.5 * dt));
    let k3 = f(&(*state + k2 * 0.5 * dt));
    let k4 = f(&(*state + k3 * dt));

    *state += (k1 + k2 * 2.0 + k3 * 2.0 + k4) * (1.0 / 6.0 * dt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also: what is the name of the problem that I am trying to solve?

I am not aware of any specific name.

> What am I doing wrong here?

Look more carefully at the `Add` [trait definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html):

```
pub trait Add<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;

    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

There is a defaulted parameter (when typing `Add`) denoting the type of the right-hand argument: unless specified this parameter will be `Self`.

This is exactly what the error message is telling you:

> ```
> ^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found floating-point number
> ```

You specified `T: Add<Output = Self>`, and thus the right-hand argument is supposed to be a `T` and `0.5` is a literal, not a `T`.

---

You can solve this problem in one of several ways:

1. Mixed Arithmetic: Implement `Add<f32>` or `Add<f64>` for `T`, and specify `T: Add<fXX, Output = Self>` as a bound.
2. Infallible Conversion: Add a supplementary bound `T: From<f32>` (or `T: From<f64>`) and convert the literals to `T` prior to attempting the operation.
3. Custom Trait: Create a new trait with the constants you need, and implement the trait for all the `T` you'd like.

While appealing, mixed-arithmetic is probably not the solution you want if `T` is intended to be a primitive, as you cannot add the implementations yourself.

Infallible conversion works well if *any* `f32` (or `f64`) can be converted to a `T`. Using `TryFrom` would allow fallible conversion, but would also require returning the error, which would worsen ergonomics.

The latter Custom Trait approach is more heavy-handed, but allows circumventing the limitations of the previous approaches.

Which way to use depends on what `T` is supposed to be. I personally favor Infallible Conversion if possible as it's a lightweight requirement -- doesn't require implementing 5 or 10 traits -- or a Custom Trait if conversion cannot be infallible.

Comment: That is very helpful right now. Just one thing: Do you mean "Mul" instead of Add? Because in my case I only want to add T's together (with Output=T), But require Mul to return T as well.

Comment: @exocortex: All numeric traits follow the same convention, I used `Add` because it's the first alphabetically though indeed in your case `Mul` seems to be the issue.

Comment: Oh wow Thank you! I just solved this. My actual error was that I tried to use this: " ... + Mul<Rhs = f64, Output = T> + ... ". I actually read the trait implementation but didn't understand that the 'Rhs = ' is to be omitted. Now with just "Mul<f64, Output = T>" and "Add<T, Output = T> + Copy" it actually works! Haha! Thank you very much! 

(should I also put a longer anser to my own question here? I feel a longer explanation for my level of rust-understanding would be cool)

Comment: @exocortex: Certainly feel free to; it's been a long time since I was a beginner so I have blind spots.